# How to save a Keras Regressor model from Colab to Google Drive?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I am trying to save regressor model after learning in Google drive. I have recently started exploring Machine learning and found Colab useful but unable to upload the model. I have python code for local machine but I am not sure how to upload it in Google drive.

**Edit:** I tried to do this

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

name  = 'dll_28'
addr = '/content/drive/My Drive/learning/'
```

but when I run the code it gives the following error

```
"Transport endpoint is not connected: '/content/drive/My Drive/learning/model_dll_28.json'"
```

```
sc_X = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1))
sc_y = StandardScaler()

sX_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)
sy_train = sc_y.fit_transform(y_train)
sX_test  = sc_X.transform    (X_test )
sy_test  = sc_y.transform    (y_test )




#==================================================================
#********************  Learning  **********************************
#==================================================================

# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import losses
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
import tensorflow.keras.initializers as init


# Initialising the ANN
reg = Sequential()
reg.add(Dense(units = 32, kernel_initializer = init.glorot_uniform(), activation = 'relu', input_dim = 6))
reg.add(Dense(units = 64, kernel_initializer = init.glorot_uniform(), activation = 'relu'))
reg.add(Dense(units = 128, kernel_initializer = init.glorot_uniform(), activation = 'relu'))
reg.add(Dense(units = 32, kernel_initializer = init.glorot_uniform(), activation = 'relu'))
reg.add(Dense(units = 2, kernel_initializer = init.glorot_uniform(), activation = 'linear'))

# Compiling the ANN
reg.compile(optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),loss = losses.mse)


# Fitting the ANN to the Training set
reg.fit(sX_train, sy_train, batch_size = 256, epochs = 500)

score = reg.evaluate(sX_test, sy_test, batch_size = 250)
print(score)
#plt.hist(y[:,2]);

#==================================================================
#********************  Saving the regressor  **********************
#==================================================================

import pickle
name  = 'dll_28'
addr = homefolder + '/reg_files/dll_28/'

reg_json=reg.to_json()
with open(addr+'model_'+name+'.json', "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(reg_json)
reg.save_weights(addr+'reg_'+name+'.h5')  

from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(sc_X, addr+'scX_'+name+'.pkl') 
joblib.dump(sc_y, addr+'scY_'+name+'.pkl')
pickle.dump( reg.get_weights(), open( addr+'w8_'+name+'.p', "wb" ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

What about instead of using Google Drive, you use [Google Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage) instead. To interact with Google Storage you can use TensorFlow io utils. For example:
[tf.io.gfile.GFile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/gfile/GFile).

To setup access credentials to your account in Google Cloud in your notebook, you can use the following logic:

```py
from google.colab import auth

auth.authenticate_user()
```

By default, the [tf.keras.Model](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.1/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L159-L2634), won't support directly reading or writing to `gs://`, so you have two options. You save it locally and then copy it by reading it and writing it into Google Storage using `tf.io.gfile.GFile`. Or you can apply the fix implemented [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/11636/files) in the keras library, not available yet in the tensorflow version.